# p5.play dynamic objects moving towards each other and stopping without bouncing away from each other

Tags: javascript, sprite, p5.js, p5.play

Im trying to program a Age of War like game. This game is programmed in p5.js with the p5.play library. Im having trouble having sprites moving towards each other and stopping and then activating a function. I'am currently changing the collisions of the sprites form static to dynamic to keep them from bouncing away from each other. But every other run the sprites bounces away from each other. Can anybody help me

```
class SpriteBuilder {
  constructor(Type, Team) {
    if (Type == "Melee") {
      this.Melee = new Melee(Team);
      this.ApplyTeam(this.Melee.Sprite, Team);
    }
  }

  ApplyTeam(Sprite, Team) {
    if (Team == "Left") {
      Sprite.color = "Blue";
      Sprite.pos = { x: 10, y: 480 };
    }
    if (Team == "Right") {
      Sprite.color = "Red";
      Sprite.pos = { x: 690, y: 480 };
    }
  }
}

class Melee {
  constructor(Team) {
    this.Team = Team;
    if (Team == "Left") {
      this.Sprite = new Sprite();
      TeamLeft.push(this);
    }
    if (Team == "Right") {
      this.Sprite = new Sprite();
      TeamRight.push(this);
    }
    this.Attackinterval;
    this.currentTarget;
    this.life = 200;
    this.Sprite.width = 20;
    this.Sprite.height = 20;
    this.Sprite.text = "Me";
    this.Sprite.textColor = "White";
    this.Move()
  }
  
  Move(){
    if (this.Team=="Left"){
      this.Sprite.collider="d"
      this.Sprite.direction="Right"
      this.Sprite.speed=1
    }
    if (this.Team=="Right"){
      this.Sprite.collider="d"
      this.Sprite.direction="Left"
      this.Sprite.speed=1
    }
    
  }
  CollideCheck() {
    if (this.Team == "Left") {
      //Collide Red Blue
      for (let i = 0; i < TeamRight.length; i++) {
        if (TeamRight[i].Sprite.collides(this.Sprite)) {
          this.Sprite.collider = "s";
          TeamRight[i].Sprite.collider="s";
          this.DealDamage(TeamRight[i]);
          console.log("Rød skader")
        }
      }
      
      //Collide Red Red
      for (let i = 0; i < TeamLeft.length; i++) {
        if (TeamLeft[i].Sprite.collides(this.Sprite)) {
          this.Sprite.collider = "s";
          TeamLeft[i].Sprite.collider = "s";
        }
      }
      
    }
    if (this.Team == "Right") {
      //Collide Blue Red
      for (let i = 0; i < TeamLeft.length; i++) {
        if (TeamLeft[i].Sprite.collides(this.Sprite)) {
          this.Sprite.collider = "s";
          TeamLeft[i].Sprite.collider="s";
          
          this.DealDamage(TeamLeft[i]);
          console.log("Blå skader")
          
        }
      }
      
      //Collide Blue Blue
      for (let i = 0; i < TeamRight.length; i++) {
        if (TeamRight[i].Sprite.collides(this.Sprite)) {
          this.Sprite.collider = "s";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  AmIDead() {
    
    console.log(this.life);
    
    if (this.life <= 0) {
      if (this.Team == "Left") {
        let index = TeamLeft.indexOf(this.Sprite);
        TeamLeft.splice(index, 1);
      }
      if (this.Team == "Right") {
        let index = TeamRight.indexOf(this.Sprite);
        TeamRight.splice(index, 1);
      }
      this.Sprite.remove();
    }    
  }

  DealDamage(CollidedSprite) {
    if (this.Attackinterval!=null)clearInterval(this.Attackinterval);
  
    
    
    this.Attackinterval = setInterval(
      () => {
        if (CollidedSprite == null) {
          clearInterval(this.Attackinterval);
        } else {
          CollidedSprite.life -= 10;
        }
      },

      1000
    );
  }

  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the sprites' physics colliders dynamic, static colliders aren't supposed to be moved, but check for if the sprites overlap, then they will not bounce off each other, which is what happens when two sprites collide.

Take a look at the [collect coin example](https://p5play.org/learn/sprite.html?page=6).